# How to categoryFilter for a column that can't be displayed within Google Charts datatable

Tags: google-visualization

I am using Google Charts with a datatable build up like this:

> 'Created', 'Passed', 'Passed with Bugs','In
> Process','Failed','Untested','Retest','Blocked','Functionality']
> "August 31, 2020",1,10,3,5,23,0,0,"Functionality1"
> "August 31, 2020",5,4,23,1,39,0,0,"Functionality2"
> "August 31, 2020",1,10,3,5,23,0,0,"Functionality3"
> "September 6, 2020",1,10,3,5,23,0,0,"Functionality1"
> "September 6, 2020",5,4,23,1,39,0,0,"Functionality2"

I am grouping values by column 0 (date) and the visualization is done in a stacked Columnchart like this:
[ColumnChart Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbDQG.png)

Since I am mixing up numbers (columns 1-7) with a string (column 8) I create a DataView without column 8. If I don't do this I get the error "All series on a given axis must be of the same data type".

Still I would like to have column 8 to use it within a ControlWrapper as a "CategoryFilter".
E.g. draw the columnChar only showing "Functionality1" data.

Below my code. It is a mix of Jinja (running a Flask webserver) and javascript:

```
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var dataArrayTests = new Array();
    </script>

{% for item in test_details %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        dataArrayTests.push([
            '{{ item["created"] }}',
            parseInt('{{ item["Passed"] }}'),
            parseInt('{{ item["Passed with bugs found"] }}'),
            parseInt('{{ item["In Process"] }}'),
            parseInt('{{ item["Failed"] }}'),
            parseInt('{{ item["Untested"] }}'),
            parseInt('{{ item["Retest"] }}'),
            parseInt('{{ item["Blocked"] }}'),
            '{{ functionality }}'
        ]);
    </script>
{% endfor %}   

  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load("current", {packages:['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawDashboard);
    dataArrayTests.reverse()
    dataArrayTests.unshift(['Created', 'Passed', 'Passed with Bugs','In Process','Failed','Untested','Retest','Blocked','Functionality'])

    // Load the Visualization API and the controls package.
    // Packages for all the other charts you need will be loaded
    // automatically by the system.
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart', 'controls']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawDashboard);

    function drawDashboard() {
    // Everything is loaded. Assemble your dashboard...

      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArrayTests);

      var result = google.visualization.data.group(
          data,
          [0],
          [{'column': 1, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'},
          {'column': 2, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'},
          {'column': 3, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'},
          {'column': 4, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'},
          {'column': 5, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'},
          {'column': 6, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'},
          {'column': 7, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'}
        ]
      )
      var options = {
        height: 600,
        legend: { position: 'top' },
        bar: { groupWidth: '75%' },
        isStacked: true,
      };

    // Create a dashboard.
    var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

    // Create a Category Filter, passing some options
    var functionalityFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
        'containerId': 'filter_div',
        'options': {
             //This gives an error right now since there is no column 8 in the view I create below. Index from 0-7 works without errors ... but these are not the columns I want to filter by
            'filterColumnIndex' : 8 
        }
    });

    // Create a ColumnChart, passing some options
    var columnStack = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'ColumnChart',
        'containerId': 'chart_div',
        'options': {
            "height": 600,
            "legend": { position: 'top' },
            "bar": { groupWidth: '75%' },
            "isStacked": true,
        }
    });

    // Create a view to filter out column 8 to avoid the error "All series on a given axis must be of the same data type"
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(result)
    view.setColumns([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]);

    dashboard.bind(functionalityFilter, columnStack)
    dashboard.draw(view);
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: The ChartWrapper has a 'view' option to let you effectively create a DataView from the incoming data.

Answer (score 0):

Found the mistake(s).

1. When pushing to "dataArrayTests" I had a typo in the last column. {{ functionality }} should have been {{ item['functionality']}} . So the column I wanted to filter on was never filled with data and could not function.
2. Within the dataArray I now define the "functionality" (column 8) with the role "tooltip". That way it does not get considered for the x-axis, but I can still use to to filter.

Adjusted code below:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var dataArrayTests = new Array();
    </script>

{% for item in test_details %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        dataArrayTests.push([
            '{{ item["created"] }}',
            parseInt('{{ item["Passed"] }}'),
            parseInt('{{ item["Passed with bugs found"] }}'),
            parseInt('{{ item["In Process"] }}'),
            parseInt('{{ item["Failed"] }}'),
            parseInt('{{ item["Untested"] }}'),
            parseInt('{{ item["Retest"] }}'),
            parseInt('{{ item["Blocked"] }}'),
            '{{ item["functionality"] }}'
        ]);
    </script>
{% endfor %}   

  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load("current", {packages:['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawDashboard);
    dataArrayTests.reverse()
    dataArrayTests.unshift(['Created', 'Passed', 'Passed with Bugs','In Process','Failed','Untested','Retest','Blocked',{type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'}])

    // Load the Visualization API and the controls package.
    // Packages for all the other charts you need will be loaded
    // automatically by the system.
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart', 'controls']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawDashboard);

    function drawDashboard() {
    // Everything is loaded. Assemble your dashboard...
        console.log(dataArrayTests)
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArrayTests);

      var result = google.visualization.data.group(
          data,
          [0],
          [{'column': 1, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'},
          {'column': 2, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'},
          {'column': 3, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'},
          {'column': 4, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'},
          {'column': 5, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'},
          {'column': 6, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'},
          {'column': 7, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'},
        ])

        result.sort([{column: 0}])

      var options = {
        height: 600,
        legend: { position: 'top' },
        bar: { groupWidth: '75%' },
        isStacked: true,
      };

    // Create a dashboard.
    var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

    // Create a Category Filter, passing some options
    var functionalityFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
        'containerId': 'filter_div',
        'options': {
            'filterColumnIndex' : 8
        }
    });

    // Create a ColumnChart, passing some options
    var columnStack = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'ColumnChart',
        'containerId': 'chart_div',
        'options': {
            "height": 600,
            "legend": { position: 'top' },
            "bar": { groupWidth: '75%' },
            "isStacked": true
        }
    });
    
    dashboard.bind(functionalityFilter, columnStack)
    dashboard.draw(data);
  }
  </script>
```